# using xslt to rename node to node's name concatenated with its index

Tags: xml, xslt, xls

I use the below xslt to transform xmls, it iterates thru the Receipt/Process
nodes and adds type attributes to the nodes. Based on the node's value it will be string/int/float.
That part works fine.

I also should rename the "Node" node to "Node" concatenated with its index and 
add an attribute which should be the "Name" node's value.

I may have multiple "Nodes" which I would like to convert to something like this:

first Node  to where the "Cuda3DLut" is coming from the `<Name>Cuda3DLut</Name>`

```
<Node1 type="Cuda3DLut" >
<Input  type="ToolLink" role="Input" format="red,green,blue">Source</Input>
<Lut type="string">Identity</Lut>
<Output type="ToolLink" role="Output" format="red,green,blue">RESULT1</Output>
<bypass type="int">0</bypass>
<nodeRole type="string">viewing</nodeRole>
<nodeShortName type="string">LUT</nodeShortName>
</Node1>
```

second Node  to

```
<Node2 type="CudaTool" >
...
</Node2>
```

I also would like to change the "Input" node's value if it is "MainMedia" to "Source" but only then.

Thanks a lot.

```
Source XML:

<Receipt>

  <Process>
    <Node>
      <Name>Cuda3DLut</Name>
      <Input>MainMedia</Input>
      <Lut>Identity</Lut>
      <Output>RESULT1</Output>
      <bypass>0</bypass>
      <nodeRole>viewing</nodeRole>
      <nodeShortName>LUT</nodeShortName>
    </Node>
   <Node>
      <Name>CudaTool</Name>
      <Input>MainMedia</Input>
      <Lut>Identity</Lut>
      <Output>RESULT1</Output>
      <bypass>0</bypass>
      <nodeRole>viewing</nodeRole>
      <nodeShortName>LUT</nodeShortName>
    </Node>
  </Process>

  <Encode>
    <Job>
     ...
    </Job>
  </Encode>

</Receipt>

xslt: 

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <cut>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>        
    </cut>
 </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="Process">

      <xsl:for-each select="Node/*">

        <xsl:choose>

            <xsl:when test="name() = 'Input'">

              <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:attribute name="type">ToolLink</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="role">Input</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="format">red,green,blue</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
              </xsl:copy>              

            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="name() = 'Output'">
              <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:attribute name="type">ToolLink</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="role">Output</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="format">red,green,blue</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
              </xsl:copy>              

            </xsl:when>

          <xsl:otherwise>

            <!-- Add type attribute to the node based on its value -->
            <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="number(.) = .">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(., '.')">
                <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:attribute name="type">float</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
                </xsl:copy>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:attribute name="type">int</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
                </xsl:copy>
              </xsl:otherwise>
             </xsl:choose>                                      
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:attribute name="type">string</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
              </xsl:copy>            
            </xsl:otherwise>            
          </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:otherwise>            
        </xsl:choose>

      </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Encode">    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You missed to show us a lot of important things, like: 1) The wanted result; 2) the requirements that the transformation must implement. Please, edit the question and provide these -- we can't read your mind. Also, the code you provided contradicts (does something contrary to) your requirement how the `type` attribute should be generated.

Comment: Hello Dimitre, I updated the post. Regards

Comment: Thanks, Gabor. Please, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Node">
     <xsl:element name="Node{position()}">
       <xsl:attribute name="type">
         <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::Name)]"/>
     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Node/*" priority="-1">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="type">string</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Node/Input">
   <Input  type="ToolLink" role="Input" format="red,green,blue">Source</Input>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Output">
   <Output  type="ToolLink" role="Output" format="red,green,blue">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </Output>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="bypass">
  <bypass type="int"><xsl:value-of select="."/></bypass>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Receipt>
    <Process>
        <Node>
            <Name>Cuda3DLut</Name>
            <Input>MainMedia</Input>
            <Lut>Identity</Lut>
            <Output>RESULT1</Output>
            <bypass>0</bypass>
            <nodeRole>viewing</nodeRole>
            <nodeShortName>LUT</nodeShortName>
        </Node>
        <Node>
            <Name>CudaTool</Name>
            <Input>MainMedia</Input>
            <Lut>Identity</Lut>
            <Output>RESULT1</Output>
            <bypass>0</bypass>
            <nodeRole>viewing</nodeRole>
            <nodeShortName>LUT</nodeShortName>
        </Node>
    </Process>
    <Encode>
        <Job>      ...     </Job>
    </Encode>
</Receipt>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Node1 type="Cuda3DLut">
   <Input type="ToolLink" role="Input" format="red,green,blue">Source</Input>
   <Lut type="string">Identity</Lut>
   <Output type="ToolLink" role="Output" format="red,green,blue">RESULT1</Output>
   <bypass type="int">0</bypass>
   <nodeRole type="string">viewing</nodeRole>
   <nodeShortName type="string">LUT</nodeShortName>
</Node1>
<Node2 type="CudaTool">
   <Input type="ToolLink" role="Input" format="red,green,blue">Source</Input>
   <Lut type="string">Identity</Lut>
   <Output type="ToolLink" role="Output" format="red,green,blue">RESULT1</Output>
   <bypass type="int">0</bypass>
   <nodeRole type="string">viewing</nodeRole>
   <nodeShortName type="string">LUT</nodeShortName>
</Node2>
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitre. Unfortunately the tag names under the "Node" may change so I need to figure out the type based on the values. It also can be the case that I need to make exceptions later for the type detection.  I try to combine your solutions with the for-each type detection. No luck yet. Thanks again.

Comment: @GaborForgacs: You are welcome. The type of this processing doesn't need or depend on `xsl:for-each` at all. Do try to avoid `xsl:for-each` and instead concentrate on the functionality.

Comment: @GaborForgacs: The fact that you "need to figure out the type based on the values" means that you still don't know exactly what you want. This answer solves the exact problem you define in your question -- how to generate elements with names like `Nodexxx` -- and the solution is shorter and simpler than what is proposed in the currently accepted answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I am new - at least according to my activity - on stack overflow and I just wanted to give some credit to the other answer I was not aware that will be the accepted answer. Mostly I agree with you, unfortunately I have a moving target, like 40 different kinds of nodes which may change anytime and I should translate to them, the main difference - with an unknown number of exceptions when it is not possible to detect the types from the value - that the type attributes are missing from the nodes.After educating myself on XSLT/ XPATH I am switching to your advised approach. Cheers

Comment: @GaborForgacs: The way to solve a complex problem is to split it into smaller ones. Then for each smaller problem you can ask a separate question at SO. I recommend this over trying to formulate a problem that is huge and difficult to define precisely.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can generate your node with `<xsl:element/>` and the `position()` function.

```
<xsl:template match="Receipt/Process/Node">
    <xsl:variable name="nodename">
        <xsl:text>Node</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$nodename}">
        ...
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I don't know a lot about the template usage unfortunately, I am unsure how I should add your template to get the expected result so basically to have the Node1 / Node2 /... nodes and all the childs below in hierarchy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I see you used `<xsl:for-each/>`, you can use this loop on your `<Node/>` elements instead of my template, and put my `<xsl:variable/>`+`<xsl:element/>` inside. However you should document yourself about templates, it's great to use them!